# Matrix rotation in numpy python, diffrent vector's length

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, 2d, transpose

I want to make a 2D game in pygame, and to do so, I want to use mathematical Matrices. Tought I'm thinking right, but I got a problem. Here it is: So I make a random point and I count length of it's vector(from 0,0), then, by using equation of matrix transplation (2D) I want to move that point, for let's say +1 degree. And i got a result, but wait, why is length of the transplated vector diffrent then the other one? All answers will be appreciated, thx :)

Here is my code:

```
import numpy
import math
import random

#length of wector    
def R(w0):
    #start point coordinates
    x0 = y0 = 0
    #new point coordinates    
    x1 = w0[0][0]
    y1 = w0[1][0]
    r = math.sqrt((x1 - x0)**2 + (y1-y0)**2)
    return r 

#matrix rotation by 1 deg
rad = math.pi/180
Tm = numpy.matrix([[math.acos(rad),-math.asin(rad)], [math.asin(rad), math.acos(rad)]]) 

#w0
x0 = random.randint(1, 5)
y0 = random.randint(1, 5)

w0 = numpy.matrix([[x0],[y0]])
r0 = R(w0)

print "x0: ",w0[0][0], "y0: ",w0[1][0], "r0: ", r0
#w0'

w1 = Tm * w0
r1 = R(w1)
print "x1: ",w1[0][0], "y1: ",w1[1][0], "r1: ", r1
```

As u can see, the r0 and r1 are diffrent :/

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `arccos` and `arcsin` instead of the `cos` and `sin` in your rotation matrix. Fix that and the two vectors have the same length, as they should.

Also you can use `np.linalg.norm` for the vectorlength.